# Will we have an SDK for elementary OS?

Tags: system, development

Does the developer team have any plans to produce an SDk for the operating system?
I imagine the great effort to produce a larger application.

Comment: As people have already stated, elementary already has a development kit. It includes a compiler, editor and documentation on how to develop applications for the platform. If this is not what you would consider a "development kit", please expand your question to include details on what you mean by SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

And:

```
sudo apt install -y elementary-sdk
```

If you need any help to start:

Source: [Youtube - Video Tutorials by Alessandro Castellani](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z0NVCrJr6A&list=PLriKzYyLb28mn2lS3c5yqMHgLREi7kR9-&index=2&t=0s)

Source: https://developer.elementary.io

Answer (score 0):

It is challenging to give you a definitive answer, because ideas of what an SDK should include differ. Some components that come to mind:

- development library headers -- these are available in the elementary PPAs or you can find them in some other distribution repositories
- an integrated development environment -- elementary code comes to mind, but Glade or GNOME Builder could be useful as well

TL;DR https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started